# Android Take Photo successfully

Tags: android, memory, camera, heap-memory

This might sound like a strange/silly question. But hear me out.

> Android applications are, at least on the T-Mobile G1, **limited to 16
>   MB of heap**.

And it takes 4 bytes per pixel to store an image (in Bitmap form):

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
    Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(_data, 0, _data.length);
}
```

**So 1 image, at 6 Megapixels takes up 24MB of heap. (*Cue Memory overflow*).**

Now I am very much aware of the ability to decode with parameters, to effectively reduce the size of the image. I even have a method which will scale it down to a desired size.

**But what about in the scenario when I want to use the camera as a quality camera!**

I have no idea how to get this image into the database. As soon as I decode, it errors.

**Note:** I need(?) to convert it to Bitmap so that I can rotate it before storing it.

So to sum it up:

- Limited to 16MB of heap
- Image takes up 24MB of heap
- Not enough space to take and manipulate an image

This doesnt address the problem, but I Recommend it as a starting point for others who are just loading images from a location:
 [Displaying Bitmaps on android](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of a couple of things that might help, none of them are optimal

1. Do your rotations server side
2. Store the data from the capture directly to the SDCARD without decoding it, then rotate it chunk by chunk using the file system, then send that to your DB. Lots of examples on the web (if your angles are simple, 90 180 etc) though this would be time consuming since IO operations against SDCARD's are not exactly fast.
3. When you decode drop the alpha channel, this may not solve you issue though and if you are using a matrix to rotate the image then you would need a target/source anyway

   Options opt = new Options();

   opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

   // Decode the raw camera a bitmap with no alpha channel
   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(raw, 0,raw.length, opt);

---

There may be a better way to do this, but since your device is so limited in heap etc. I can't think of any.

It would be nice if there was an optional file based matrix method (which in general is what I am suggesting as option 2) or some kind of "paging" system for Android but that's the best I can come up.

Comment: This really is the smartest way to accomplish your goal. Ideally you want to do any heavy lifting server side because your phone doesn't have much processing power, especially a G1.

Comment: I actually test on a HTC One X, but that fails to do the operation due to application heap size limitation. Plus it needs to work on OS 10 anyway. Thanks for suggestions will try number 2 tomorrow. Looking at 3, its going to drop only 1 of the 4 channels. My camera is 8 Megapixels so still 24MB, plus the less memory used anyway the better.

Comment: @idistic - To preview it properly in portrait mode I some android given code that sets `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result)`. AKa what I see in the preview. It just occured to me that this isnt suppose to rotate the camera, and infact I then found the proper method to rotate Camera within Camera `Parameters`. `mParameters.setRotation(90);` This way I dont have to create a bitmap, and hence can store straight to the Database a 1MB JPEG array. Some good alternatives though from yourself. If you want to add a number 4. That would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

First save it to the filesystem, do your operations with the file from the filesystem...

Comment: Its being stored as an array (rotated) in a database.

Comment: @Doomsknight - Why not just store paths to the images in the DB and then store the actual images on the file system?

Comment: Because it syncs up with a desktop App DB, along with other devices. Its much easier just to pass an array around than having to update image references depending on the devices storing location.

Comment: If the image is being synced, then it is probably being stored on a server somewhere? Perhaps you could pull down small portions of the image from the db, work on them, rinse and repeat. If they're already in a db, you don't need to have the entire image in memory at once.

Comment: via USB when connected to the PC with the main DB location on it. I didnt think it was possible to rotate an image without its full contents? Especially if its JPEG byte array, since its a compression.